# How to stash changes and pull from master

Tags: git

I'm working on project with git for the first time. 
I made some changes after I cloned the project, now I want to update my project from master (git pull) . when I tried to do it I got the msg:

Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting

I have one file that I want to keep the changes in it (without uploading it to master), and a few files that I don't care about them, meaning I want to ignore the changes I made, and accept the code from master.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The git error states it clearly.

```
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge. Aborting
```

If you want to get the latest changes from master without overriding your local changes, you can either commit your changes or do a git stash.

To perform a stash, execute **git stash** then do a `git fetch origin master && git merge master` or `git pull master`.

To retrieve your changes from the stash, do a `git stash pop` which will get the changes from the top of the stash.

For more information about this, please refer to the [git stash documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)

Comment: It doesn't answer my question. I don't want commit my changes in the json file, I just to keep it like that in my own project. Moreover, how can I stash changes in part of my project? As I said before, there are files I don't want to stash the changes in them.